# Unflatten a HashMap of values

Tags: java

I currently have a Map of key value pairs in the format of

```
a.b.c: value1
e.f: value2
g: [
  g.h: nested_value1
  g.i: nested_value2
]
```

and I need to 'unflatten' this to a new Map in a nested structure -

```
a:
  b:
    c: value1
e:
  f: value2
g: [
  h: nested_value1
  i: nested_value2
]
```

My current attempt doesn't get very far, and throws a ConcurrentModificationException

```
private static Map<String, Object> unflatten(Map<String, Object> flattened) {
    Map<String, Object> unflattened = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : flattened.keySet()) {
        doUnflatten(flattened, unflattened, key, flattened.get(key));
    }
    return unflattened;
}

private static Map<String, Object> doUnflatten(
    Map<String, Object> flattened,
    Map<String, Object> unflattened,
    String key,
    Object value) {

    String[] parts = StringUtils.split(key, '.');
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        String part = parts[i];
        Object current = flattened.get(part);
        if (i == (parts.length - 1)) {
            unflattened.put(part, value);
        } else if (current == null) {
            if ((current = unflattened.get(part)) == null) {
                current = new HashMap<>();
            }
            unflattened.put(part, current);
            unflattened = (Map<String, Object>) current;
        } else if (current instanceof Map) {
            unflattened.put(part, current);
            unflattened = (Map<String, Object>) current;
        }
    }
    return unflattened;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? One solution is to use a library like JsonFlattener - the only issue is this would involve converting back and forward between JSON alot.

Edit: Thanks for the pointers - I am half way there, one thing I forgot to mention was it also needs to unflatten a collection of HashMaps

Comment: well, you are modifying the same object you are iterating. maybe you should try creating an new hashmap per key and attach it to another new hashmap.

Comment: Instead of modifying the Map you pass as an argument you could change your function to build and return a new map that is "unflattened".

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes because you iterate the key set and then change the map, not through the iterator.

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view
>   methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

You could get around this by using a new map.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `Map` instance for your result instead of attempting to reuse the current one. Also, send in the map value, so it doesn't need to be extracted:

```
private static Map<String, Object> unflatten(Map<String, Object> flattened) {
    Map<String, Object> unflattened = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : flattened.keySet()) {
        doUnflatten(unflattened, key, flattened.get(key));
    }
    return unflattened;
}
```

This also prevents the original keys from being present in the resulting map.

The above also requires a slight rewrite of the `doUnflatten` method:

```
private static void doUnflatten(Map<String, Object> current, String key,
  Object originalValue) {
    String[] parts = StringUtils.split(key, ".");
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        String part = parts[i];
        if (i == (parts.length - 1)) {
            current.put(part, originalValue);
            return;
        }

        Map<String, Object> nestedMap = (Map<String, Object>) current.get(part);
        if (nestedMap == null) {
            nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
            current.put(part, nestedMap);
        }

        current = nestedMap;
    }
}
```

Couple of notes: There's no need to return the map from the method. Divide the loop into two distinct cases: Either the value should be written to the map, or a nested map should be created or retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that you are writing the output into the same `Map` that you use for the input, which causes `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Implementation becomes straightforward with a separate `Map` for output:

```
Map<String,Object> unflattened = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e : flattened.entrySet()) {
    String[] parts = StringUtils.split(e.getKey(), ".");
    // Find the map to be used as a destination for put(...)
    Map<String,Object> dest = unflattened;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != parts.length-1 ; i++) {
        Object tmp = dest.get(parts[i]);
        if (tmp == null) {
            // We did not see this branch yet
            Map<String,Object> next = new HashMap<>();
            dest.put(parts[i], next);
            dest = next;
            continue;
        }
        if (!(temp instanceof Map)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        dest = (Map<String,Object>)temp;
    }
    // Put the entry into the destination Map<>
    dest.put(parts[parts.length-1], e.getValue());
}
```

Note that the process of "unflattening" may fail when the initial map describes an inconsistent hierarchy, for example, one with a branch and a leaf having the same name:

```
"a.b.c" -> "x" // OK: "a.b" is a branch
"a.b.d" -> "y" // OK: "a.b" is a branch
"a.b"   -> "z" // Error: "a.b" is a leaf
```

Comment: Yes just noticed I would be overwriting values myself - needed to check whether that leaf is already in the new Map or not!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to replace line

```
for (String key : flattened.keySet()) {
```

to

```
for (String key : new ArrayList<>(flattened.keySet())) {
```

but for large data amount it can be not very effective from performance perspective.